# GeoDjango Order by distance for Model that is linked to User who has a location on their user profile

Tags: distance, geodjango

I need to order my query model by distance, however the point field in question is not on the model class but on the user profile and the i am getting an error when attempting the following.

```
g = geocoders.Google(domain='maps.google.co.uk')
place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode('SW1')  
MyModel.objects.distance(Point(lat, lng), field_name='user__userprofile__location').order_by('distance')
```

The error i get is "ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields"

Both MyModel and UserProfile have a GeoManager but obviously User does not.

Filtering works fine using

```
MyModel.objects.filter(user__userprofile__location__distance_lte=(Point(lat, lng), D(mi=distance)))
```

But I can't understand why sorting is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Did anyone figure this one out already to the end?
Two options I have tried so far:
**Proxy model**

```
class GeoUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    # Define managers
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

**add_to_class**

```
class GeoUserManager(models.GeoManager):
    objects = models.GeoManager()


User.add_to_class('objects', GeoUserManager())
```

But I keep hitting "ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields. ()" ... Everything is a point and using field_name

```
queryset=User.objects.filter(userprofile__open=True).distance(pnt, field_name='userprofile__location').order_by('distance'))
```

Don't know if this could help.

**Update 06/10/2012**

So I have been further investigating into this and I'm still not quite getting there.
When building a queryset and defining the field_name, I receive mentioned error about GeometryFields.  I even went so far to update the auth.User in contrib to include the GeoManager, but this did not change anything.
When however building the queryset straight on UserProfile and thus not having to define field_name, things Just Work.  Don't know if this is a bug? Since I have found some posts on the net that confirm field_name is working...

Comment: Ok, so some strange behaviour I noticed in further digging, updated the answer...

Comment: I am having similar issues, any thoughts? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107588/geodjango-order-bydistance-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 2):

in geodjango, as you know **ST_Distance** operation can use with Geography columns. The error you get is `"ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields`" about lack of the geographic field in your model.

The more important think is that **if you want to make spatial lookup, GeoManager is required even if the model does not have a geographic field itself**, e.g., in the case of a ForeignKey relation to a model with a geographic field.

you can get some information about GeoManager [here](http://packages.python.org/django_simple_feedback/ref/contrib/gis/model-api.html).

**GeoManager**

> In order to conduct geographic queries, each geographic model requires
>   a GeoManager model manager. This manager allows for the proper SQL
>   construction for geographic queries; thus, without it, all geographic
>   filters will fail. It should also be noted that GeoManager is required
>   even if the model does not have a geographic field itself, e.g., in
>   the case of a ForeignKey relation to a model with a geographic field.
>   For example, if we had an Address model with a ForeignKey to our
>   Zipcode model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField

class Address(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField()
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = USStateField()
    zipcode = models.ForeignKey(Zipcode)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

The geographic manager is needed to do spatial queries on related Zipcode objects, for example:

```
qs = Address.objects.filter(zipcode__poly__contains='POINT(-104.590948 38.319914)')
```

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am not sure how this helps.

Are you saying my User class requires a GeoManager and if so how do I add one as I am just using the django auth User model

Comment: You can extend your user with adding geomanger to it. There is an information [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/) about extending User model.

Comment: That link explains how to add a UserProfile which i have as previously explained, my UserProfile model does have a geomanager but i think because i am going from my MyModel class through User to UserProfile it is failing because User does not have a geomanager but i could be wrong. Im sure there must be a way to resolve this.